# jquery background color change on button click

Tags: jquery, colors, background

Why doesnt this work?

### jquery

```
$("#button").click(function(){ 
 $("go").css("background-color","yellow");
 });
```

### html

```
<table><tr id=go bgcolor=#010609><td>hello</td></tr</table>
<input type=button id=button>
```

Comment: $("#go") -> # for id, . for a class

Answer (score 21):

`go` is an id :

```
$("#button").click(function(){ 
    $("#go").css("background-color","yellow");
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Your selector for `go` is wrong.

Try

```
$('#go').css({backgroundColor: 'yellow'});
```